# gccでのコンパイル時に表示されるエラーメッセージの意味がわからない

Tags: c

現在ハッシュテーブルを使い、人物の検索をかければその人の年代が出てくるコードを書いています。下記の三つのソースコードをターミナルで`gcc -c hash.c`、`gcc -c openaddr.c`、`gcc -c main.c`とかけたところ、エラーが出てしまいました。なぜこのエラーメッセージが出てきしまうのかがわかりません。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
openaddr.c:30:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hash' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int hs = hash(id1);
             ^
openaddr.c:86:34: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
                    printf("id: %s,  info: %d\n");}
                                ~^
openaddr.c:30:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hash' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int hs = hash(id1);
             ^
openaddr.c:86:34: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
                    printf("id: %s,  info: %d\n");}
                                ~^
2 warnings generated.
main.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'initialize' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    initialize();
    ^
main.c:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'enter' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    enter("Copernicus", 1473);
    ^
main.c:11:40: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hash' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("enter Copernicus at %d\n", hash("Copernicus"));
                                       ^
main.c:22:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'show_table' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    show_table();
    ^
main.c:24:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'search' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    t = search(key);
        ^
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define M 257
#define NEXT_HASH(x) (x + 1) % M

int hash(char *v){
    int x=0;
    while (*v) x= 256*x + (*v++);
    if (x < 0) x = (-x);
    return (x % M);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define M 257
#define NEXT_HASH(x) (x + 1) % M

struct item {
    char id[20];
    int info;
};

struct item table[M];

void initialize() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        memset(table[i].id, '\0', sizeof(table[i].id));
}

void show_table() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        if (strcmp(table[i].id, "") != 0)
            printf("[%3d] id: %20s,  info: %d\n", i, table[i].id, table[i].info);
}

int enter(char *id1, int info1) {
    int i;
    int hs = hash(id1);

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(table[hs].id, "")) {
            strcpy(table[hs].id, id1);
            table[hs].info = info1;
            return 0;
        }
        hs = NEXT_HASH(hs);
    }
    return -1;
}

int search(char *id1) {
    int hs = hash(id1);
    int next = hs;
    while(hs == hash(table[next].id)) {
        if (!strcmp(table[next].id, id1))
            return next;
        next = NEXT_HASH(next);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int qflag = 1;
    char str[20];
    int n, cmd;
    int cancel();
    int hashcode =search(str);

    while(qflag) {
        printf("1.. INSERT  2.. CANCEL  3.. SEARCH  4.. LIST  0..EXIT\n");
        scanf("%d", &cmd);

        switch(cmd) {
            case 1:
                printf("id   >> ");
                scanf("%s", str);
                printf("info >> ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                enter(str, n);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("id  >> ");
                scanf("%s", str);
                    //if(!strcmp(str, "%s"))
                    //memset(str, '0', sizeof(str));
                    //printf("%s canceled\n", str);
                break;
            case 3:

                printf("id  >> ");
                scanf("%s", str);
                if (hashcode ==0){
                    printf("%s fonded\n", str);
                    printf("id: %s,  info: %d\n");}
                else if (hashcode != 0){
                    printf("%s not found\n", str);}               
                break;
            case 4:
                show_table();
                break;
            case 0:
                qflag = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 257

int main(){
    int t;
    char key[20];
    initialize();
    enter("Copernicus", 1473);
    printf("enter Copernicus at %d\n", hash("Copernicus"));
    enter("Galilei", 1564);
    printf("enter Galilei at %d\n",hash("Galilei"));
    enter("Newton", 1643);
    printf("enter Newton at %d\n",hash("Newton"));
    enter("Maxwell", 1831);
    printf("enter Maxwell at %d\n",hash("Maxwell"));
    enter("Einstein", 1879);
    printf("enter Einstein at %d\n",hash("Einstein"));
    enter("Heisenberg", 1901);
    printf("enter Heisenberg at %d\n",hash("Heisenberg"));
    show_table();
    strcpy(key, "Heisenberg");
    t = search(key);
    printf("%s => %d\n", key, t);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

出力されているのは「エラー」でなくて「警告」です。で、そのエラーメッセージの内容がよくわからないようなら、日本語に翻訳してみましたか？

まず簡単なほう

> more '%' conversions than data arguments

% による変換指定が、実引数より多いです。

`printf` 系関数は、フォーマット指定 `%s` をしたなら `char*` 型の値が、 `%d` をしたなら `int` 型の値が必要です。

> printf("id: %s,  info: %d\n");

には値がないです。 (`%s` に対応する値 `%d` に対応する値）

---

面倒なほう

> implicit declaration of function 'hash' is invalid in C99

関数 'hash' の暗黙の宣言は C99 では不正です。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) や [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) では、分割コンパイルをする際にはソースファイルとヘッダファイルをペアで作る必要があります。 (例えば `hash.c` と `hash.h` というファイルをペアにする)

そして、その機能を使う別の C ソース中に `#include "hash.h"` のように書いてヘッダファイルを読み込ませる必要があります。これを怠ると「関数の暗黙宣言」となり、この警告が出ます。

質問文中、どの引用が何というファイルなのかわかりませんが、分割コンパイル＋リンクを行いたい様子なので、正しく「ヘッダファイルを作る＋ `#include` する」を行うと警告は消えるでしょう。

ヘッダファイルに何を書く、ソースファイルに何を書くあたりの解説を始めると本が１冊書けちゃうので、ご自分で調査の上わからないところがあれば再質問してください。

Comment: どうすれば%s、%dそれぞれに対応する値を入れることができますか？

Comment: また正しく「ヘッダファイルを作る＋ #include する」というのは二つ目のプログラミングのはじめに、#include "main.c"と書けばいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 前者は「あなたが表示したいもの」を追加してください。あなたが何を表示したいのかは、読者にはわかりません。 `printf("...", 変数１, 変数２);` みたいに。後者を解説すると長くなります。新しい「質問」を挙げてくれると jSO 的にうれしいです。