# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)の対処法

Tags: c

macのターミナルで`gcc hash.o openaddr.o main.o -o ssort`と行ったところ、

```
duplicate symbol _hash in:
    hash.o
    openaddr.o
duplicate symbol _enter in:
    openaddr.o
    main.o
duplicate symbol _hash in:
    hash.o
    main.o
duplicate symbol _search in:
    openaddr.o
    main.o
duplicate symbol _initialize in:
    openaddr.o
    main.o
duplicate symbol _show_table in:
    openaddr.o
    main.o
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

というエラーが表示されました。
現在Visual studio codeでプログラムを書き、ターミナルで動かしています。
どのような対処をすればいいのかを教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: その表示でわかるのはリンカーが失敗したと言うことだけです。ターミナルに表示されたのは、本当にそのメッセージだけですか?(普通はもっといろんな情報が表示されます。)ターミナルに表示されたメッセージの全文を問題文中に示してください。

Comment: [別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54999/13972)の回答に示された「ヘッダファイルを作る＋ #include する」が正しく行えていないようですね。現在のhash.h、hash.c、openaddr.h、openaddr.c、main.cの内容を全てご質問中に含めてください。

Comment: 別質問でもお答えいただいたのですが、やはり「ヘッダファイルを作る＋ #include する」というのがどう行えばいいのかがわかりません

Comment: 回答の文章をきちんと読まれていないのではありませんか?「ヘッダファイルを作る＋ #include する」と言うのは単なる要約であり、「ソースファイルとヘッダファイルをペアで作る必要があります。 (例えば hash.c と hash.h というファイルをペアにする)

そして、その機能を使う別の C ソース中に #include "hash.h" のように書いてヘッダファイルを読み込ませる必要があります。」と書いてあるのですが、hash.hファイルを作ろうともしていないと言うことですか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージを文字通り訳してみてください。

> duplicate symbol _hash in ...

`_hash` という名前が ... で重複しています。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) でこのエラーが出るのは「正しくソース＋ヘッダのファイル分割ができていない」からです（他の言語ではまた違う原因があるかもしれません）。どう対処すればよいか、は「分割コンパイルの際に求められる流儀に正しく従う」です。

具体的にどうすればよいかは、前にも書きましたが「正しく理解して頂くには結構な分量の解説が必要」です。この件 [c](/questions/tagged/c) 言語の初期の頃から４０年近く経っていますが皆同じようにハマっています。ハマった人が色々解説記事を書いていますので、まずは検索していろいろ読んでください。 `#include "hash.c"` と書くのが誤りで、こう書くと `duplicate symbol` エラーが出る、という解説記事は探せばすぐ見つかるでしょう。

オイラがここ stackoverflow で解説記事書いてもいいんですけど、まずはご自分で検索＋思考してみてください。それでもわからない点があればピンポイントで質問してください。（オイラに限らず）詳しい人が喜んで解説してくれるでしょう。